# How do I get a part of string in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a set of strings that satisfy the following pattern: *sometext_number*. So, I always have a number after '_' symbol. Is there a convenient way to get that number from a string regardless of its size?

Comment: Use std::regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sure that you always have *"sometext_number"*, you can test the following solutions:

Using [`QString::split()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split):

```
QString str = "hello_1234";
int number = str.split('_').last().toInt();
```

Using [`QRegularExpression::match()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#match):

```
QString str = "world_5678";
QRegularExpression regex("\\w+_(?<number>\\d+)");
QRegularExpressionMatch m = regex.match(str);
int number = m.captured("number").toInt();
```

Comment: This is better than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `QString` anyways, you can do

```
QString s = "sometext_5";
int index = s.indexOf("_");
int number = s.mid(index+1).toInt();
```

Comment: You won't need your last sentence if you use -1 (which is the default) as the second parameter to [`mid`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#mid) which returns all the characters. And then your answer is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **std::find**, which returns you the index of the element you're looking at, and then use **substr** on your string, given in parameter the index where you want to stop splitting

Comment: I believe QString has no `substr` member.

Comment: Correct, and no `find` either.